# highchart highstock not display full yAxis data

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

`yAxis` just display data from range -500 to 250. However, the graph has data points which value are larger than 250 but not display on the graph
[image]

Comment: Hi @jasonB, That is probably caused by the `dataGrouping` feature: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.scatter.dataGrouping Please try to disable it and let me know the result.

Comment: hi @ppotaczek, thank you for helping me out. It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is caused by the `dataGrouping` feature. You can disable it by:

```
plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

---

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.scatter.dataGrouping